# Joining a stream against a "table" in Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

Let me use a slightly contrived example to explain what I'm trying to do. Imagine I have a stream of trades coming in, with the stock symbol, share count, and price: `{ symbol = "GOOG", count = 30, price = 200 }`. I want to enrich these events with the name of the stock, in this case `"Google"`.

For this purpose I want to, **inside Dataflow**, maintain a "table" of symbol->name mappings that is updated by a `PCollection<KV<String, String>>`, and join my stream of trades with this table, yielding e.g. a `PCollection<KV<Trade, String>>`.

This seems like a thoroughly fundamental use case for stream processing applications, yet I'm having a hard time figuring out how to accomplish this in Dataflow. I know it's possible in Kafka Streams.

Note that I do **not** want to use an external database for the lookups – I need to solve this problem inside Dataflow or switch to Kafka Streams.

Comment: Could you provide more information about the source of the enrichment data?  Specifically -- is it static?  Per-key?  Globally?  Is it being joined against multiple keys?  How many total keys?

Comment: @SamMcVeety the enrichment data is dynamic, being updated constantly (about one new element per key per hour). There will at least be millions of keys, possibly hundreds of millions.

Comment: If joins were key-aware it would be possible to make sure that elements with the same keys from either collection would be handled by the same node, allowing proper scaling...

Comment: Do these keys ever age out?  It seems like otherwise, you are expecting the pipeline to store an unbounded amount of data, indefinitely.

Comment: Ben's posted a detailed set of options below.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to describe two options. One using side-inputs which should work with the current version of Dataflow (1.X) and one using state within a `DoFn` which should be part of the upcoming Dataflow (2.X).

## Solution for Dataflow 1.X, using side inputs

The general idea here is to use a map-valued [side-input](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/par-do#side-inputs) to make the symbol->name mapping available to all the workers.

This table will need to be in the global window (so nothing ever ages out), will need to be triggered every element (or as often as you want new updates to be produced), and accumulate elements across all firings. It will also need some logic to take the latest name for each symbol.

The downside to this solution is that the entire lookup table will be regenerated every time a new entry comes in and it will not be immediately pushed to all workers. Rather, each will get the new mapping "at some point" in the future.

At a high level, this pipeline might look something like (I haven't tested this code, so there may be some types):

```java
PCollection<KV<Symbol, Name>> symbolToNameInput = ...;
final PCollectionView<Map<Symbol, Iterable<Name>>> symbolToNames = symbolToNameInput
  .apply(Window.into(GlobalWindows.of())
      .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterProcessingTime
          .pastFirstElementInPane()
          .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(5)))
      .accumulatingFiredPanes())
  .apply(View.asMultiMap())
```

Note that we had to use `viewAsMultiMap` here. This means that we actually build up *all* the names for every symbol. When we look things up we'll need make sure to take the latest name in the iterable.

```java
PCollection<Detail> symbolDetails = ...;
symbolDetails
  .apply(ParDo.withSideInputs(symbolToNames).of(new DoFn<Detail, AugmentedDetails>() {
    @Override
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
      Iterable<Name> names = c.sideInput(symbolToNames).get(c.element().symbol());
      Name name = chooseName(names);
      c.output(augmentDetails(c.element(), name)); 
    }
  }));
```

## Solution for Dataflow 2.X, using the State API

This solution uses a new feature that will be part of the upcoming Dataflow 2.0 release. It is not yet part of the preview releases (currently Dataflow 2.0-beta1) but you can watch the [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/release-notes/release-notes-java-2) to see when it is available.

The general idea is that keyed state allows us to store some values associated with the specific key. In this case, we're going to remember the latest "name" value we've seen.

Before running the stateful `DoFn` we're going to wrap each element into a common element type (a `NameOrDetails`) object. This would look something like the following:

```java
// Convert SymbolToName entries to KV<Symbol, NameOrDetails>
PCollection<KV<Symbol, NameOrDetails>> left = symbolToName
  .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<SymbolToName, KV<Symbol, NameOrDetails>>() {
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
      SymbolToName e = c.element();
      c.output(KV.of(e.getSymbol(), NameOrDetails.name(e.getName())));
    }
  });

// Convert detailed entries to KV<Symbol, NameOrDetails>
PCollection<KV<Symbol, NameOrDetails>> right = details
  .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<Details, KV<Symbol, NameOrDetails>>() {
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
      Details e = c.element();
      c.output(KV.of(e.getSymobl(), NameOrDetails.details(e)));
    }
});

// Flatten the two streams together
PCollectionList.of(left).and(right)
  .apply(Flatten.create())
  .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<Symbol, NameOrDetails>, AugmentedDetails>() {
    @StateId("name")
    private final StateSpec<ValueState<String>> nameSpec = 
      StateSpecs.value(StringUtf8Coder.of());

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c
      @StateId("name") ValueState<String> nameState) {
      NameOrValue e = c.element().getValue();
      if (e.isName()) {
        nameState.write(e.getName());
      } else {
      String name = nameState.read();
      if (name == null) {
        // Use symbol if we haven't received a mapping yet.
        name = c.element().getKey();
      }
     c.output(e.getDetails().withName(name));
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is... sort of a crazy amount of code to write to accomplish something I would imagine most streaming applications would need. Is this really being done in practice? There are no higher-level constructs that make sense, or maybe are on the roadmap?